# Retrofit пустой json от сервера

Tags: android, retrofit

нужно сделать textview видимым, когда от сервера приходит пустой json `{"cities":[]}` Как это можно отловить?

```
adapter = new CityAdapter(response.body().getCities(),getActivity());
            if(response.body().getCities().toString().equals("[]")){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Нету данных",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                emptyTV.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            }
            Log.e("body",response.body().getCities().toString());
            Log.e("adapter",adapter.toString());
```

Log:

```
E/body: []
E/adapter: com.example.danilshik.testapplication.helper.CityAdapter@536e01a8
```

Временно сделал с помощью .equals(), но думаю есть и более правильный способ

Класс:

```
public class Cities {
    private ArrayList<City> cities;

    public Cities() {
    }

    public ArrayList<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
}
```

Comment: а `getCities` что возвращает?

Comment: @Komdosh возвращает список городов, добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, вы получаете ответ от сервера в виде "{"cities":[]}" .

В данном случае у вас есть массив cities, размер которого равен 0.

Соответственно вам нужно проверять равен ли размер массива 0 или нет.

```
  if(response.body().getCities().size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Нету данных",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            emptyTV.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно проверить пустой ли лист?

```
response.body().getCities().isEmpty()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty()

Comment: вы маленько не поняли, либо не я так выразился, ответ хоть как приходит, но пустой: {"cities":[]}. Как его проверить кроме моего варианта? И лог внимательно посмотрите

Comment: @danilshik ну и проверяйте, не понимаю в чем проблема, мы вызываете `toString()` на пустом листе и получаете в лог "[]", ну проверьте этот лист на пустоту.